# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' everything looks fine

Tags: php, mysql

I want to insert some information into a MySQL table but in the line of code where I'm inserting the info, it keeps giving me the same error.

The problem is in the first line of code.

I checked any parentheses I maybe forgot to add or square brackets or curly brackets. I don't see any problems but maybe you will. Could you please help me?

for some reason this if statement doesn't want to be inside the box of code.

```
if(mysql_num_rows($sql2==1) {

        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, email, password) VALUES (:username, :email, :password)";

        if($stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            $stmt->bindParam(":username", $param_username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(":email", $param_email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(":password", $param_password, PDO::PARAM_STR);

            // Set parameters
            $param_username = $username;
            $param_email = $email;
            $param_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT); // Creates a password hash

            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if($stmt->execute()){
                // Redirect to login page
                header("location: login.php");
            } else{
                echo "Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }
        }

        // Close statement
        unset($stmt);
    }
```

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';'

Comment: Just use a linter: https://phpcodechecker.com/

Comment: OMG thank you that is just wonderful!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do it like this:

```
if (mysql_num_rows($sql2) == 1) {
    //ur code
}
```

You forgot a ")" and are asking a qustion inside a pdo function

It also give the response of "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' everything looks fine"

because the function mysql_num_rows cant handle "=="

**EDIT**

the function `mysql_num_rows` is deprecated use `mysqli_num_rows()` instead

read the docs [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php)